# MySQL/PHP - Comparing columns of rows in array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

hope you are well the problem that i am having is comparing two values in a array the (columns) of rows.

Is there a way to just check those columns match as i am only checking two rows or is a for each loop the only way.

I am able to get all the data and place it into an array but the if statement i am using does not work in comparing.

```
  if ($countReport == 2) {
        while ($rowReport = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultReport)) {    
        $temp_array[] = $rowReport;
        }
        //if (in_array("Hello, world",array_count_values($temp_array))){
        //echo "working";
        //} 
    }
```

This is the data in the array, the stats column is what i am trying to compare like are both values equal to "hello world".

```
[{"abcID":"8","stats":"Hello, world","time":"23:30:00"},
{"abcID":"7","stats":"Hi, world","time":"23:16:00"},]
```

Comment: Use your dark magic attack to eliminate that wild closing bracket.

Comment: `$countReport = 2` should be `$countReport == 2`

Comment: The attack failed, i just commented that out now. Using that if statement gives an error of only integer and string values. Probably going to try with for each instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
<?
foreach($array as $k1=>$v1)
{
    echo $k1; //returned abcID
    echo $v2 //returned 8
  foreach ($array2 as $k2 => $v2) {
    echo $k2; //returned abcID
    echo $v2 //returned 7
        if($k1==$k2 && $k1=='stats')
        {

                if($v1==$v2)
                $newarray[]=$v1; //added if they are equal or do what u want.

        }
  }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: (this is my duh moment, I was overthinking this problem from the start.)

The logical process (no functions or loops are necessary) if you only have the two rows returned is to do a literal check:

```
if($temp_array[0]['stats']!=$temp_array[1]['stats']){
    echo "no match";
}else{
    echo "duplicate";
}
```

---

The following one-liners deliver the same outcome, but do so less efficiently....

Here is a one-liner for your condition statement requiring no loops:

Example 1:

```
$temp_array=array(
    array("abcID"=>"8","stats"=>"Hello, world","time"=>"23:30:00"),
    array("abcID"=>"7","stats"=>"Hi, world","time"=>"23:16:00")
);

if(sizeof(array_unique(array_column($temp_array,"stats")))>1){
    echo "no match";
}else{
    echo "duplicate";
}
// displays: no match
```

Example 2:

```
$temp_array=array(
    array("abcID"=>"8","stats"=>"Hello, world","time"=>"23:30:00"),
    array("abcID"=>"7","stats"=>"Hello, world","time"=>"23:16:00")
);
if(sizeof(array_unique(array_column($temp_array,"stats")))>1){
    echo "no match";
}else{
    echo "duplicate";
}
// displays: duplicate
```

The breakdown:

```
sizeof(                                    // count the size of the remaining array
    array_unique(                          // remove duplicates from array
        array_column($temp_array,"stats")  // array of values where 'stats' was the key
    )
)
```

---

Come to think of it, there are probably several ways to skin this cat.

Here's another:

```
if(current(array_count_values(array_column($temp_array,"stats")))==1){
    echo "no match";
}else{
    echo "duplicate";
}
```

I'm not sure it's worth going on and on.

Comment: @Dark-Magician You will find my top snippet to be unbeatable.  Please mark it as the accepted answer so that your question is deemed resolved.